# 404 (Not Found) при запросе POST

Tags: javascript, fetch

Получаю 404 (Not Found) при запросе POST, бэк исправен, через постман все работает. Помогите, пожалуйста, понять в чем ошибка

Мой код

```
...else if (authButton.checked){
        const url = "http://95.163.235.3:4444/login";
        const data = {
            email: emailField.value,
            password: passField.value
        };
        console.log(data);

        return postData(url, data)
        .then((data) => {
        console.log(data); 
        });
    } 

const postData = async(url, data) =>{
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://95.163.235.3:4444/login", {
            mode: "no-cors",
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        const json = await response.json();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Ошибка:', err);
    }
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

**Вопрос решен.**

В запросе необходимо передавать `mode: "cors"`, если на бэке используется CORS

Соответственно при `mode: "cors"` необходимо установить CORS на бэк и прописать в хидерах ответа соответствующие заголовки

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

И соответственно подключить CORS

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));
```